# Equation containing modified bessel functions and exponential function

Tags: special-functions, exponential-function

I'm trying to find a approximation solution for the following equation:
${e^{ - x}}\left[ {{I_o}\left( x \right) + {I_1}\left( x \right)} \right] = C$
where $I_0$ and $I_1$ is the modified Bessel functions of the first kind of order 0 and 1. C is a constant.
Do you have any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the limit of large $x$, the left hand side looks like $\sqrt{2/(\pi x)}$, which results in equation that is easily soluble for $x$, so long as $C$ is sufficiently small.

Comment: For small $x$, I used the relation ${I_1}\left( x \right) = {I_0}\left( x \right)\frac{x}{2}{e^{\frac{{ - {x^2}}}{8}}}$. And when x is small, $I_0(x)=1$. We obtain: ${e^{ - x}}\left[ {1 + \frac{x}{2}{e^{\frac{{ - {x^2}}}{8}}}} \right] \simeq {e^{ - x}}\left[ {1 + \frac{x}{2}} \right] \simeq \left( {1 - x + \frac{{{x^2}}}{2}} \right)\left( {1 + \frac{x}{2}} \right) = C$. 
The solution for the above cubic equation can be found in wikipedia.

Comment: The relation between $I_0(x)$ and $I_1(x)$ can be found in: "Exponential Approximation of the Modified Bessel Function".